# Using a shell command to set docker's VM memory size to 6GB

Tags: windows, macos, docker

I have a docker image that only runs if there are 6GB of RAM available. Unfortunately on Windows and Macs the docker VM is limited to 2GB by default. You need to go to the Docker advanced settings to change this. This is something I'd rather not have my users do.

Is there a shell command (or Powershell command on Windows) that changes this limit? I'd much rather tell my users they should run one command from the terminal, than have them mess with the advanced Docker settings.

Answer (score 0):

With `docker for windows`, gui settings are stored in `C:\Users\$YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`, also could be simplified as `~\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`, in it you will find something like next:

```
{
    ......
    "memoryMiB": 2048,
    ......
}
```

The default memory hyper-v machine used is `2048M`, you can change it to any value you needed then restart the docker to meet your requirement.

You can use any method to modify the file & restart docker just as you like. Next is a sample powershell script for your reference:

**a.ps1:**

```
(get-content ~\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json) | foreach-object {$_ -replace '"memoryMiB":.*', '"memoryMiB": 3072,'} | set-content ~\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json

net stop docker
net stop com.docker.service
taskkill /IM "dockerd.exe" /F
taskkill /IM "Docker for Windows.exe" /F
net start docker
net start com.docker.service
& "c:\program files\docker\docker\Docker for Windows.exe"
```

**Execute in powershell (NOTE: need to run as administrator):**

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\abc\a.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Above will run `a.ps1` in which it will change memory value & restart the docker, after that, the memory will just what you needed. You may change some path in the script based on your real situations on your computer.